# how to publish multiple sub-report in jasper server

Tags: jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

how to publish a main report which has multiple sub-reports for example main report A consists of a sub-report B and sub-report B consists of sub-report C and they have different parameters, for example report B has different parameter and report c has different parameter. i can able to publish all three reports but i am getting an error with arguments (parameters are unable to call) from the main report

Comment: please share the jrxml files with error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you connected all the subreports(and subdatasets) with your main report,
(simple right click on dataset and option to connect to main dataset) and make sure to configure your jasper server of .jrxml so that it includes all the necessary resources

The studio "knows" where it can find all the required files, but the "knowledge" ends there.